# 50 Projects in 50 Days - GitHub Link

Tags: github

I've been doing [50 Days - HTML/CSS and JavaScript](https://github.com/bradtraversy/50projects50days) by Brad.

I want to upload all my projects/folder in one repository and get the github link like on the readme section of the github link above. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Register to github.com

   1.1. Create a new repository

   1.2. Get the https of the repository and endit with a .git and keep it for later steps (https://github.com/bradtraversy/50projects50days.git)
2. Install git from google. Open git bash and execute following commands replacing " " with ur data

   2.1.  `git config --global user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME"`

   2.2.  `git config --global user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"`
3. Navigate through bash to the destination where you want to link with the repository, for instance a new folder, it must not be ur project folder (hope you now how to navigate through terminal, cd, mkdir...)
4. Now clone the repository, this will link your computer with the repository. Execute the following command:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/bradtraversy/50projects50days.git
   ```
5. Now with windows explorer or finder, just copy your projects inside this cloned repository.

6.Finally sync changes:

```
git add foldername
git commit -m "commit comment to asses what you have changed"
```